# iOS iAP: Is there some sort of transaction id I can send to my server

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I am not sure on how to handle this situation. Basically, when a user purchase a subscription in my iOS App (for a premium account) I want to send the transaction id to my server or some kind of unique purchase id. So this way if the user gets a refund from Apple I can revoke the premium account based on the id.

I am new to iAP and perhaps there might be a better way overall.

Comment: there is no way to find out if the user gets a refund from Apple. You don't receive any information about refunds

Comment: Will I still get the money in that case? Im just afraid if we offer this premium service we might get ripped off.

Comment: Nope, if the amount is refunded you just lose out.  Generally Apple won't process refunds without a good reason and if a user continually asks for refunds then Apple will note this to and deny their requests.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Actually, I should clarify. Are you using auto renew subscriptions?  If so then you can find out about refunds by checking the cancellation date in the receipt; https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH7-SW6